# XSLT: opening but not closing tags

Tags: xslt

Is there a way to open a tag and not close it? For example:

```
<xsl:for-each select=".">
       <span>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This is my code: http://pastebin.com/1Xh49YN0 . As you can see i need to open  on a when tag and close it on another when tag (row 43 and 63).

This piece of code is not valid because XSLT is not well formed, but is there a way to do a similar thing? Thank you

Comment: In order to create sensible output, surely you'd have to close it eventually.  What are you really trying to do?  If you are trying to turn a flat list of elements into set of nested spans, there are better ways.

Comment: Your example code will only produce one opening `span` tag (`.` is always a nodeset containing 1 node), so you might as well get rid of the for-each part of it for a start.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't write why i need such a thing. I updated post and added my code.

Comment: You appear to be treating XSLT as an imperative programming language, rather than a declarative templating tool.  You might benefit from a change of mindset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move the content between the two existing `xsl:choose` elements to a new template

In the `xsl:when`, open and close your `span`.  Inside the `span`, call this new template.

Add an `xsl:otherwise` to the `xsl:choose`, in this, call the template, without adding a `span`.

As a general point, try to use `xsl:apply-templates` a bit more often, rather than `xsl:for-each`, it should make it easier to understand what is going on.

Comment: indeed, I can't think when I've ever used it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't - XSLT isn't about generating a text file or a sequence of characters, it's about transforming one document tree into another. That the tree eventually gets serialized into a textual format is incidental.

This is why, for example, you can't choose between  and  in the output file - they're both represent exactly the same document tree.

You can almost always achieve what is intended by refactoring into separate templates that call each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can use disable-output-escaping, but it's generally considered a bit of a hack, and I understand it's deprecated in XSLT 2.

Comment: `disable-output-escaping` certainly is the wrong approach to this problem, deprecated or not.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, obviously, but if I understood your original code correctly, this should be pretty close.

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$pos">
        <xsl:for-each select="$s">
            <xsl:choose>
                <!-- inizio contesto -->
                <xsl:when test="$pos[.=position()+$context_number]">
                    <xsl:text>INIZIO CONTESTO</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <!-- fine contesto -->
                <xsl:when test="$pos[.=position()-$context_number]">
                    <xsl:text>FINE CONTESTO</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <!-- parola -->
                <xsl:when test="$pos[.=position()]">
                    <span class="word"><xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- stampo tutta la riga -->
        <xsl:value-of select="$s"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Hint: `<xsl:when test="(. - $current_pos) eq 0">` is equivalent to `<xsl:when test=".=$current_pos">`. ;-)